# Is it ok to be proactive wrt the question of illegal immigration during the visa interview?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

For instance, is it acceptable to emphasize the reasons why I'm not interested in illegal immigration? Or it's a "don't talk about the elephant in the room" situation?

Comment: It probably depends on the circumstances, but there's a definite chance that the interviewer may suspect that an applicant who is eager to disavow intention to immigrate illegally is perhaps somewhat _too_ eager.

Comment: You should emphasize what you have to go back to, not why you don't want to stay

Comment: the visa interview isn't a conversation. They'll ask questions, you'll answer the questions. Be honest and concise

Comment: @Midavalo: But some questions can be quite open-ended, so it’s good to have advice on what topics are good/bad to bring up.

Comment: @PLL Even so, starting a reply with “I’m not an illegal immigration risk because…’ won’t be the right approach. Open-ended questions can still be answered factually. “Tell me why you’ve come to the US” can be answered with “I’m here for a two-week vacation from my job as a (whatever) in (wherever the traveller lives)”, for example.

Comment: @Traveller not for everyone that's enough. In any case, it's possible to emphasize _why_ you don't have reasons to go illegal, even if you don't name it overtly.

Comment: You could certainly use less contentious language to say the same things, such as "I will go back home because" rather than "I won't be an illegal immigrant because". As others have said, you want to give the best possible impression, so choose your language accordingly.

Comment: @StuartF explaining how to say this in a better way would be a great answer.

Comment: How could it not be both acceptable and indeed, desirable to emphasize why you're not interested in illegal immigration?

Answer (score 25):

This is going to be an opinion answer.

Illegal immigration is not the reason for your trip, so if you started talking about and emphasizing illegal immigration then I'd suspect the immigration people you are talking to would suddenly start to get suspicious about your motives.  And while these people can't prove any of their suspicions (no matter how hard to would deny them), they still do have the absolute power to deny you your visa.

So as per @littleadv you need to focus on what you have in your home country, and how this is just a temporary trip.

Comment: It is the primary reason why visa applications are rejected, though.

Comment: @user626528 but all the declarations in the world won’t change a thing. Evidence of ties will.

Comment: @jcaron that's unrelated to the statement that I answered.